# Declaring multiple scopes based on user input Angular-Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a `$scope` of 1 to 5 `lists`, depending on user input. In each `list` there will be an array of `items`. I have my `list` names as `list1`, `list2`....My problem is when I declare the `$scope` using `$scope.list = [];` it of course isn't going to know which list that would be. Since I am naming them statically and they have a limit of 5 I know I could declare each `list`. I feel that is a bit too heavy and not efficient. Is there a better way of declaring each `list`, based on the user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a property on your `$scope` dynamically - as with any other `javascript` object.

so, `$scope.myList = []` is the same as `$scope['myList'] = []`

using your users input it should be simple to create these list properties on your scope from your users input.

Psuedo-code could be:

```
$scope.myButtonClick = function(){
     // where userInput is a number
     for (i = 0; i < userInput; i++){
         $scope['list' + (i+1).toString()] = [];
    }    
}
```

Comment: I like it. I'm still new to Angular, I didn't think of doing that.

Comment: It's all good :) this is something you can do in plain old `javascript` too :)